# "Cannot access com.google.common.base.Predicate" in Selenide

Tags: maven, selenium, guava, selenide

I am new to Selenide and I tried to follow this video: https://vimeo.com/107647158 at 8:05 - part

`$("#ires li.g").shouldHave`

is underlined with `"Cannot access com.google.common.base.Predicate"` error.

I tried some Google and found this: [What is the fix for class file for com.google.common.base.predicate not found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992160/what-is-the-fix-for-class-file-for-com-google-common-base-predicate-not-found) which pointed to https://github.com/google/guava page.

I added dependency to pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.company.myFirstSelenideTest</groupId>
  <artifactId>myFirstSelenideTest</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <name>metadataTestonDPU</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenide</artifactId>
      <version>4.12.3</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
      <version>25.1-jre</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
          <fork>true</fork>
          <executable>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\javac</executable>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

But it didn't resolve my issue.

I also checked `%JAVA_HOME%` and path to JDK/JRE and seems to be fine. What I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, duck method...

I added `import com.google.common.base.Predicate;` on the top and IntelliJ IDEA posted on red `Predicate` part with a tip to add it to a classpath

Sorry for dumb question

Comment: I had the same problem and your fix has worked for me as well, although it's weird we have to manually add a library to the classpath once we use Maven to manage our project dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue for Predicate & Collect, then added below and it worked

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava-base</artifactId>
    <version>r03</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava-collections</artifactId>
    <version>r03</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Springfox 3.x removes dependencies on guava and other 3rd party libraries (not zero dep yet! depends on spring plugin and open api libraries for annotations and models) so if you used guava predicates/functions those will need to transition to java 8 function interfaces